# Transistor absolute maximum Collector-Base voltage more than Collector-Emitter voltage

Tags: bjt, device-characteristics

In the [Microsemi 2N918](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/8811-lds-0010-pdf) NPN RF transistor datasheet, the absolute maximum ratings are given as:

[image: ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS table from Microsemi 2N918 datasheet]

The fact that \$V_{CBO}\$ is so much greater than \$V_{CEO}\$ has me confused. Additionally, the datasheet specifies \$V_{CB}\$ at 25V and 30V for certain parameter test conditions later in the document.

My question is: for a BJT, what in the construction/manufacturing process makes \$V_{CBO} > V_{CEO}\$?

Comment: Obviously Vcb can't be much higher than Vce (0.6V comes to mind), but you would not normally leave the base open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make the terms explicit, \$V_{cbo}\$ is the maximum voltage that can be applied between the collector and base of a BJT while the emitter is left unconnected, and \$V_{ceo}\$ is the maximum voltage that can be applied between the collector and emitter of a BJT while the base is left unconnected. There is a huge difference between these situations.

With the \$V_{cbo}\$ case, some leakage flows between the collector and the base and this may cause the part to warm up a little. This is just a diode involved, though. So in this case, they just specify the voltage below which the part isn't damaged and from which the BJT can recover itself.

With the \$V_{ceo}\$ case, it's similar in a lot of ways. But now we aren't talking about a diode, but the entire transistor structure. So with the base open, any leakage current will also become an enabling base current, which of course is then amplified by the transistor's \$\beta\$. So that will lead to still more current, etc., heating it up still more.

That's the main reason I'm aware of why it's often true that \$V_{cbo} > V_{ceo}\$.

Comment: The base amplification is an interesting aspect. It's definitely part of the device construction (and operation) that causes this. Your explanation of the test conditions help clarify that. However, your answer doesn't really address my second question.

Comment: I didn't really understand your question there. I'll edit my answer to pose the my quandary. Perhaps you can then clarify and I can then attempt to answer, if I have an answer.

Comment: It may just be that I'm not well enough acquainted with BJTs. Would it be more useful to remove the second question? It came from my thought following wondering why there was an unexpected difference in specification that was if that difference was useful for something. I should also qualify that second question with operation (if possible) in the \$15V <V_{CB} < 30V\$ range, maybe not being concerned about the relation with \$V_{CE}\$.

Comment: Well, I'm just not sure. If you can point to a datasheet and point to something specific on that datasheet, I'll go look. The context will be there. I was kind of thinking you might be asking about saturation vs active mode operation. But I just don't know.

Comment: I'll put it down to being arbitrarily curious and out of context, given that this about the *maximum* ratings and I have no particular example for 'reasonable' transistor operation. I'll remove the second question and that will leave everything before your `EDIT:` as an acceptable answer.

Comment: I've now edited my question, so you can remove your edit to best suit the Q&A.